# How do I make it asynchronous?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, redis, synchronization, lettuce

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.session.host}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.session.port}")
    private int port;


    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(hostName);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);

        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        lettuceConnectionFactory.setShareNativeConnection(false);//커넥션 공유 여부 설정, 기본값은 true
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }
    /*
    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(hostName, port);
    }*/
    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

```java
//Method of service class that uses cache
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheNames.TOP_STORE, key="#type.name().concat('-').concat(#n)")
    public List<TopStoreResponse> getStoresTopN(StoreSearchType type, int n){
        return storeRepository.findTopNByType(n, type.name(), "desc");
    }
```

If you look at the example codes using lettuce, there is no separate asynchronous or synchronous setting.
If I don't configure it, does lettuce work synchronously by default?

1. Is it faster if I change it to asynchronous?
2. How do I make it asynchronous?